# What exactly is a .jar file and how do i create one?

Tags: jar

What exactly is a .jar file and how do i create one?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+jar+file

Comment: Googlelable questions are perfectly valid if you look at the FAQ.

Comment: @HeavyWave: No one is saying that this question isn't valid.

Comment: If you don't know what one is, how do you know that you *want* to create one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)), JAR is an archive format used by Java to combine classes into one application or library.

It is essentially a zip archive with some additional information, such as a manifest.

To create one just use jar command inside the folder where you store your classes.

```
jar -cf my.jar *.class
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean when you say to use those commands inside that folder. do i do this from the command line or do i make a program in the folder that does this or soemthing else? what do i do?

Comment: jar is a command line tool, part of the Java, the same as java and javac commands. There is a tutorial at sun's website http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html