# Creating My Own Library Of Utilities

Tags: java

I have written a program that has a couple of utility classes.  Right now I have the class embedded in my program but I would like to pull it out to a JAR file that I can then use in multiple programs.  I am not asking how to import a JAR but, instead, how to create a JAR from my utility class.  It seems this must have been asked elsewhere but all of the references I have found have focused on how to import a JAR file into a project.

I am familiar with exporting my java program to a JAR file in Eclipse.  But I thought that only made a runnable JAR.  So from what I understand from the comments if I package my utility class into its own package and export to a runnable JAR I can just include that JAR in my programs to use the API.  Did not realize it was that simple.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604177/what-exactly-is-a-jar-file-and-how-do-i-create-one

Comment: have you searched for how to `export` as jar?

Comment: What is the environment that you are developing on? Are you using the JDK directly, or are you using an IDE, like Eclipse? The steps differ depending on your particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to extract those classes into their own package, and then bundle them into a redistributable jar file.

If you're using an IDE like Intellij or Eclipse, they will do this automatically. Otherwise, you should take a look at the docs on how to do it manually:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html